# Why does SSL_READ pause for a few seconds before reading from the socket?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

I am trying to write a very very simple program to connect to a server send a request and read the reponse back. The program is using OpenSSL for TLS support. The code compiles and runs. After the call to `SSL_write` the code then gets to the `SSL_read` function. At this point, the program hangs for about 10 seconds, before reading any data. Any ideas what I would need to do to avoid the wait?

```c
#include <netdb.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define HOST "geminiprotocol.net"
#define REQUEST "gemini://geminiprotocol.net/"
#define PORT "1965"
#define BUFMAX 100

int create_socket(int *fd) {
  int res, sock;
  struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  if ((res = getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));
    return res;
  }

  for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sock = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
      continue;
    }

    if (connect(sock, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
      continue;
    }

    break;
  }

  if (p == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

  *fd = sock;
  return 0;
}

int read_body(SSL *ssl) {
  char buf[BUFMAX + 1];
  int ret;

  while ((ret = SSL_read(ssl, &buf, BUFMAX)) > 0) {
    buf[ret] = '\0';
    printf("%s", buf);
  }

  if (ret == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  return -1;
}

int main(void) {
  int fd, ret;
  SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
  SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
  if (!ctx) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create SSL CTX\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("Created Context\n");

  SSL* ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
  if (!ssl) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create SSL\n");
    exit(2);
  }
  printf("Created SSL\n");

  if (create_socket(&fd)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not create socket\n");
    exit(7);
  }
  printf("Created Socket\n");

  if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, fd)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not set ssl fd\n");
    exit(3);
  }
  printf("Set FD\n");

  SSL_set_connect_state(ssl);

  if ((ret = SSL_connect(ssl)) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SSL_connect: %s\n", strerror(SSL_get_error(ssl, ret)));
    exit(4);
  }
  printf("SSL connected\n");

  if ((ret = SSL_write(ssl, REQUEST, strlen(REQUEST))) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SSL_write: %s\n", strerror(SSL_get_error(ssl, ret)));
    exit(5);
  }
  printf("SENT Request\n\n");

  read_body(ssl);
  printf("READ Response\n\n");

  if (fd) {
    close(fd);
  }
  SSL_free(ssl);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the server is waiting for a CR/LF as specified in the protocol? `\n` is only the newline, but I don't see you sending any end-of-line code after the URL...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes lol you are exactly right! I cant believe I missed that...

Comment: The fun thing is that I first thought of the solution and then checked if it could be correct. I guess that's called experience :)

Answer (score 0):

As Maarten Bodewes commented, the server was waiting for the `\r\n` ending to the request that the protocol specifies.